# git: best practice for committing (and logging)

Tags: git

I try to get every of my projects into git.

I see 2 possible strategies for committing (and document!) changes of code.

**A)** on a daily base and put just very simple comments into the commit-log of git
 to find details of a change diff would be the tool of choice.

**B)** permanently for every minor change (or every file changed) and the commit-log would describe the change in detail. For orientation the log would be enough instead of diff between versions of files.

I do not think it is possible in real life to have few commits AND detailed commit-logs when a project changes in multiple places during a day.

And I am not sure now is searching the logs or diffing the files is the best way to search the history.

Whats best practice normally in the git-world?

Comment: I always try to commit something if I feel the changes are relevant or some error is solved / feature is implemented. I do not think it is good to commit after each line of code. In my opinion, the commit message should be nice and clean. If you want a detailed description of the changed I would always use `git diff`. I try not to add to many details which you already see in `git diff` but add more like an overall commit message that describes what was the idea behind these changes like `implemented feature XY` or `bugfix for this error` and so on. If the feature is big then split it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a important question since [a lot of people](https://xkcd.com/1296/) actually neglect their commit list. They shouldn't because a well-organized repository drastically raise the value of a project, reaching a point where the information given, when easy to retrieve, is almost more valuable than the code itself.

In short :

- care about the commit descriptions, and tell what the changes actually do, not what you've done during a certain timelapse;
- Try to keep your repository's history as clean as your code is.

I personally have totally adopted the [Linux kernel development guidelines](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/) for my own projects. These are the ones that have seduced me the most.

It basically consists of grouping changes into "**logical units**", which could both lead you either to bulk commits or oneliners.

For example, the kernel sources come with a tool called **sparse** than scans all the C files and checks for potential semantic problems. This tool is periodically upgraded when something new is discovered and we want to clean out the whole project consequently. Among the things that needed to change, there was the removal of FSF's postal address that use to be included in the license included as a text comment at top of every source file.

For this particular case, I would gather all these changesets (truncating the top comment) into a single commit dedicated to this, that is : containing the removal of this section for every C file (even if there's 30 of them inside a subsystem directory) but nothing else. No additional code change or side modifications. Then I would prepare some other commits for the rest of my work.

This was already required before Git as most of these changes were so far (and actually still are) submitted as "patches" to a maintainer in charge of reviewing them before he decides to integrate them or not. Not only sending him a big tarball containing the work of the week with a notice "cope with this on your own" is a chance for you to see your complete work rejected, but submitting well-prepared patches enables people to optionally reject some of your patches while still accepting the most of the rest, then letting you fix the ones that cause problem and submitting them again.

Also, a common practice in a multi-user development project is to never rewrite "history"… unless all protagonists are perfectly used with Git and can handle this. However, nothing prevents you to alter your own history before publishing it. So what you can do when developing, if you don't have the time to focus on the "packaging", is to commit everything on a personal temporary branch until you're done, then cherry-pick all the stuff topic by topic onto the official development branch, verify with `git diff` if the tops of your temporary and development branches are synchronized and finally push your work.

An additional good reason to care about commits is to take the benefit of investigation commands such as `git blame`. If, for instance, you fall on row that used to control the user's identity and suddenly no longer does, not only you'll enjoy `git blame` to point to the exact commit that introduced the change, but also to quickly retrieve the whole context, with a bit of information. In this particular case, this could be due to the fact that all identity checks were centralized upstream in a dedicated function or module.

That's because Git is mainly oriented that way that certain commands such as `git add` are made to pick up file individually by default and require some options (such as **-u** or **-A**) to select everything that has been altered (unlike some others SCM such as Mercurial, which provides `addremove`, turning out to be a false good idea).

To help you doing this, you may include files one by one, of course. But you'll also want to check out:

```
git add -p
```

… to individually select hunks from a single modified file. You may then use

```
git diff
git diff --cached
```

… to check out what's still need to be added and what you already have prepared for next commit.

Finally, be sure to care about the message's body in each commit, because this is where the reason for something should be recorded. A large number of developers simply state something inside the subject line with `git commit -m` but describing a commit allows you to avoid setting this information directly in the code, keeping it clean.